# Can't resolve "Duplicate Class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzdt found in module" error,

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle

I saw a similar question asked in here but the solution didn't help me and the error is still same. I tried to make new project, but the error is still the same and I don't what's bugging! Please help me with this error, I can't deploy my app just because of this error.

Here is the error log:

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzdt found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-image-labeling-internal-16.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-image-labeling-internal:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zze found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzf found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzg found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzh found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzi found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzs found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-image-labeling-internal-16.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-image-labeling-internal:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzt found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-image-labeling-internal-16.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-image-labeling-internal:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzu found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-image-labeling-internal-16.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-image-labeling-internal:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzv found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzw found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

Here is my build.gradle(:app) file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.finalapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-image-label-model:20.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

and here is my build.gradle(Final App) file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Lower the version of dependency from *24.1.0* to *24.0.0*

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.0'
```